# How to allow project referencing my DLL to use a newer version of a DLL my project references?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, assemblyversions

I have written a dll that references Entity Framework version 5. It is also packaged as a NuGet package which has a dependency on Entity Framework >= 5.

When I install this package into another project which already has a reference to Entity Framework 6 there are no complaints about the dependency but it crashes as runtime saying it cannot find the Entity Framework 5 dll.

The reference has `SpecificVersion` set to false in my dll's project and I have tried adding a `bindingRedirect` in the web.config of the project which references my dll, but still the error occurs.

Any idea how I can get this to work or what I am missing here?

Comment: So us your package nuspec file.  If you built it automatically, just rename your package to a zip and open it and grab the nuspec file.

Comment: The nuspec was automatically generated, it has nothing but the minimal elements defining the package name, version etc.

Comment: It's the version I am interested in, need to see how it specified the version dependency on Entity Framework.  Nuget has a schema for that, https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning

Comment: e.g. setting your version in the nuspec to just 6 will allow 6 or any previous version. while setting it to (,6.0] means it can run on 6 or below but not above 6.

Comment: I also at one point had deleted the dependency manually from the package and tried that, but had the same issue.

Comment: The package specififed >= 5.0.0.0. There were no complaints about missing dependencies. The error happens at run time.

Comment: Your final issue, is probably due to nuget's patch setting in the IDE.  By default nuget packages use the minimum patch on a dependency, if you want it to use the highest you need to install the package that way, Install-Package SomePackage -DependencyVersion HighestPatch

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like package restore is just not working on it and the installed nuget package is trying to use 5.  I don't know where >= 5 is coming from, but it should be <= 6 and HighestPatch.  What version VisualStudio are you using to build the package?  I ask because nuget changed A LOT between 2013 and 2015.  Automatic package restore works differently in 2015.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90939/discussion-between-ryios-and-mclaassen).